# How can I catch a specific kind of InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, exception, invalidoperationexception

I came across a bug in my code today that would cause the following exception to be thrown when I had duplicate identifiers in my list:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

While I know I can catch this exception like so:

```cs
string id = "foo";
List<string> DirtyList = new List<string>{"foo","bar","xyzzy","foo"};
string result = null;
try{
    result = DirtyList.Single(x=>x.Equals(id));
}
catch( InvalidOperationException e )
{
    Console.WriteLine( e );
    throw;
}
```

..but this will also catch all other `InvalidOperation` exceptions, including `Sequence contains no elements`, `Sequence contains no matching element` and many others.

How can I make it so that I'm only catching the `Sequence contains more than one matching element` exception?

I want to only catch this specific exception message because I want to leave feedback in the log file of my application explaining which part of the configuration is wrong.

Comment: [Exception filter](https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/21/exception-filters-in-c-6/)?

Comment: If you want to filter on the text, simply filter on the text or a few words using multiple `if" or a switch or a dispatch table or exception filter if more convenient. But maybe you can use some [properties such as Data and HResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationException?#Properties) to refine management instead of checking the string message that can be localized... Thus see if these properties indicate different things for different messages.